# Click event doesn't working when click on Titanium ImageView

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am working on a mobile web apps for iphone. Where I got data from a web-service.
Problem is my image view is not working for click event. I have no idea about the reason...
Please help... I post my code bellow...

```
    Titanium.include('commonFile.js');

    var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

    var url = carsDetailUrl + nid;

    var imageArea = Titanium.UI.createView({
        width : 300,
        top: 50,
        height : 125,
        borderRadius : 6
    });

    var image1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image : "",
            left : '8dp',
            top : '10dp',
            width : 135,
            height : 106,
            touchEnabled : 'true',
            borderColor : '#000000',
            borderRadius : 6,
            borderWidth : 1,
        });
    var completeScrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
                top : '0dp',
                left : '0dp',
                contentWidth : 320,
                touchEnabled : 'true',
                borderRadius : 10,
                backgroundImage : '../images/bg.png',
                showHorizontalScrollIndicator : false,
                showVerticalScrollIndicator : false,
                //height : '300dp'
            });


    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onload : function() {

            var tableData = [];
            var headLines, imageLabel, i, row, viewDetail, cars, images;

            cars = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            headLines = cars.data[1];
            images = cars.data[1]['image'];

            var mainScrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
                top : '0dp',
                left : '0dp',
                contentWidth : 320,
                touchEnabled : 'true',
                borderRadius : 10,
                backgroundImage : '../images/bg.png',
                showHorizontalScrollIndicator : false,
                showVerticalScrollIndicator : false,
            });

            var viewDetail = Ti.UI.createView({
                top : '10dp',
                left : '10dp',
                height : 'auto',
                width : '94%',
                touchEnabled : 'true',
                borderRadius : 10,
                backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF',
            });

       image1.image = encodeURI(images[1]);

       /*var image1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image : encodeURI(images[1]),
            left : '8dp',
            top : '10dp',
            width : 135,
            height : 106,
            touchEnabled : 'true',
            borderColor : '#000000',
            borderRadius : 6,
            borderWidth : 1,
        });*/

            var image2 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                image : encodeURI(images[2]),
                left : '150dp',
                top : '11dp',
                width : '70dp',
                height : '50dp',
                borderColor : '#000000',
                borderRadius : 3,
                borderWidth : 1,
            });

            viewDetail.add(imageArea);
            imageArea.add(image1);
            imageArea.add(image2);

            mainScrollView.add(viewDetail);
            mainScrollView.add(view2nd);

            completeScrollView.add(mainScrollView);
            win.add(completeScrollView);

        },

        onerror : function(e) {
            alert('There was an error retrieving the remote data. Please check your internet cunnectivity.');
        },
        timeout : 45000
    });

    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.send();

image1.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {    
            Ti.API.info("image clicked");

                var newWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
                    url : '../automobileSubClass/carImageGallery.js',
                    title : nTitle,
                    tabBarHidden : true,
                    barColor : '#000000',
                    //navBarHidden : true,
                    backgroundImage : "../images/bg.png"
                });
                Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(newWin, {
                    animated : true
                });

            });
```

But if I create a Button to go to that url and then the button click working... But I need to click working when user click on the image... Please help. Thanks..

Comment: Please reduce amount of code. I can't find a click listener in your code.

Comment: @VVoo Hi, code edited... Click listener is just after the ajax finished...

Comment: set view's  height : Ti.UI.SIZE. Give background colors to check whether your views are overlapping.

Comment: i am checking as u mention @adnan
I should let you know when i am finished checking...

Comment: @adnan thank u so much... it was mainly a view overlapping problem. and i solve it.. your hint help me to find the solution. If you post an answer then definitely I am going accept it.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this code . I have set height of views and removed webservices to check your click even. Its working fine.

```
//Titanium.include('commonFile.js');

    var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
         win.backgroundColor='black';

   // var url = carsDetailUrl + nid;

    var imageArea = Titanium.UI.createView({
        width : 300,
        top: 50,
        backgroundColor:'white',
        height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
        borderRadius : 6
    });

    var image1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image : 'KS_nav_ui.png',
            left : '8dp',
            top : '10dp',
            width : 135,
            height : 106,
            backgroundColor:'blue',
            touchEnabled : 'true',
            borderColor : '#000000',
            borderRadius : 6,
            borderWidth : 1,
        });
    var completeScrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
                top : '0dp',
                left : '0dp',
                contentWidth : 320,
                touchEnabled : 'true',
                borderRadius : 10, 
               // backgroundImage : '../images/bg.png',
                showHorizontalScrollIndicator : false,
                showVerticalScrollIndicator : false,
                height : Ti.UI.SIZE
            });



            var mainScrollView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
                top : '0dp',
                left : '0dp',
                contentWidth : 320,
                touchEnabled : 'true',
                borderRadius : 10,
                backgroundColor:'yellow',
               // backgroundImage : '../images/bg.png',
                showHorizontalScrollIndicator : false,
                showVerticalScrollIndicator : false,
            });

            var viewDetail = Ti.UI.createView({
                top : '10dp',
                left : '10dp',
                height : 'auto',
                width : '94%',
                touchEnabled : 'true',
                borderRadius : 10,
                backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF',
            });



       /*var image1 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image : encodeURI(images[1]),
            left : '8dp',
            top : '10dp',
            width : 135,
            height : 106,
            touchEnabled : 'true',
            borderColor : '#000000',
            borderRadius : 6,
            borderWidth : 1,
        });*/

            var image2 = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                image :'KS_nav_views.png',
                left : '150dp',
                top : '11dp',
                width : '70dp',
                height : '50dp',
                backgroundColor:'green',
                borderColor : '#000000',
                borderRadius : 3,
                borderWidth : 1,
            });

            viewDetail.add(imageArea);
            imageArea.add(image1);
            imageArea.add(image2);

            mainScrollView.add(viewDetail);
           // mainScrollView.add(view2nd);

            completeScrollView.add(mainScrollView);
            win.add(completeScrollView);




image1.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {    
            Ti.API.info("image clicked");

                var newWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({
                    url : 'newWindow.js',
                    title : 'New Window',
                    tabBarHidden : true,
                    barColor : '#000000',
                    navBarHidden : true,
                   // backgroundImage : "../images/bg.png"
                });
                Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(newWin, {
                    animated : true
                });
```